# The maximum value?

Tags: optimization

$x^5y + y^5z + z^5x$

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be non-negative reals such that $x+y+z=1$

The maximum value of the above expression can be represented as $a^b/c^d$, where a and c are not perfect powers, and $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers. Find the value of $a+b+c+d$.

I want to know how to solve such questions. What are useful methods? What should I learn about to solve these "maximum and minimum values"?

Note: I'm a self-learner. What happened is that I saw this question on a site and many other such questions about "maximum and minimum values". My main point is to know what should I learn about to solve it (Resources would be helpful).

Comment: Learn lots of inequality theorems!
Rearrangement inequality, AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz, Jensen's, etc. All of these are on Wikipedia and they help you solve lots of problems like these!

Comment: Also, look for symmetry; lots of problems like these have solutions that are very symmetric (e.g., I haven't worked through this problem yet, but I would bet that the solution is $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @JohnChessant Honestly, I felt the same about (the 1/3 solution), but so far I can't prove it. I can't even be sure of that solution. Also, thanks for pointing out these theorems.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers can sort this out, if you know calculus. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the following answer is the better one, but it shows that $x = y = z = 1/3$ is not the optimal solution.

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^5y +y^5z+z^5x$ be the objective function. The problem is equivalent to minimize the Lagrangian function

$$ L =  -f(x,y,z) -\mu_1x-\mu_2y- \mu_3z + \lambda(x+y+z-1),$$ where $\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3$  and $\lambda$ are Lagrangian multipliers. The stationary points satisfy the polynomial system

$$ \lambda = \mu_1 + 5x^4y +z^5$$
$$ \lambda = \mu_2 + 5y^4z +x^5 $$
$$ \lambda = \mu_3 + 5z^4x + y^5 $$
$$ x + y + z =1$$
$$ \mu_1x = 0 $$ 
$$ \mu_2y = 0 $$ 
$$ \mu_3z = 0 .$$ 
$$ \mu_1 \geq 0,\mu_2 \geq 0,\mu_3 \geq 0$$

Now, we evaluate all possible cases for the multipliers $\mu_1, \mu_2$, and $\mu_3.$

**Case (1): $\mu_1, \mu_2$, and $\mu_3$ are positives**

In that case the system has no solution (the last three equations lead to $x=y=z=0$, not satisfying the equality constraint).

**Case (2): at most a multiplier is zero**

There is no solution such as all multipliers are nonnegative. Indeed, assuming $\mu_1 = 0$, we have $(x,y,z) = (1,0,0) \implies \lambda =0.$ Hence, $\mu_2 = -1$. Similarly, $\mu_2 = 0 \implies \mu_3 = -1$ or $\mu_3 = 0 \implies \mu_1 = -1$.

**Case (3): at most two multipliers are zero**

The set of solutions are $$(x,y,z) = \{(5/6,1/6,0),(1/6,0, 5/6),(0,5/6,1/6)\},$$

for $\lambda \approx 0.4019$ in all solutions, and

$$(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3) = \{(0,0, 0.4017),(0,0.4017, 0),(0.4017,0,0)\}.$$ The objective is $f(x,y,z) \approx 0.067.$

**Case (4): all multipliers are zero**

In this case, we need to solve the following system

$$ 5x^4y + z^5 = 5y^4z + x^5$$
$$ 5z^4x +y^5 = 5y^4z + x^5 $$
$$x +y +z =1, $$ which it seems to be not so simple. An idea is to compute a Grobner basis in order to simplify the system to tackle univariate polynomials. See the basis computed with WolframAlpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=grobner+%7Bx+%2B+y+%2B+z+%3D1,+5z%5E4x+%2By%5E5+%3D+5y%5E4z%2Bx%5E5,+5y%5E4z%2Bx%5E5+%3D+5x%5E4y%2Bz%5E5+%7D).

Nevertheless,I've computed the solutions of the system with the command *solve* of Matlab. It gives a total of $25$ solutions, but only four ones are real and nonnegative. The solutions given by the solver are

$$(x,y,z) = \{(1/3,1/3,1/3), (0.3631,0.5426,0.0943), (0.5426,0.0943, 0.3631), (0.0943, 0.3631, 0.5426)\}.$$

For the first solution, the objective is $f(x,y,z) \approx 0.0041$. The other three solutions give the value $f(x,y,z) \approx 0.0079$.

Thus, the optimal solution lies in the **case (3)**.

Comment: I don't know about "Lagrange multiplier" which requires a backgorund about calculus (It's my problem. I will study about these theorems), so I'm not fully understanding the solution, but I can see the main idea. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AhmedAmir, To learn about, I suggest you the Stephen Boyd and Liven Vandenberghe's book *Convex Optimization*, chapter 5.

Comment: According to Amazon, it's a really good book. https://www.amazon.com/Convex-Optimization-Stephen-Boyd/dp/0521833787 I read the introduction and I'm interested in studying the entire book. However, the author suggested to have a solid understanding in advanced calculus and advanced linear algebra. I'm working on this at the time. Thanks for the great suggestion!